# Keep scroll position and save toggle after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

A long content sub-page has multiple "read more" buttons done with jquery `toggleClass`.

When a user click the "read more" button the content is showing and the page gets refreshed. (I need the page-refresh for various reasons).

When the page gets refreshed, of course the content is not unfold anymore.

What I am trying todo is:

- Save all unfold / fold toggle content before the page-refresh.
- Go to the same scroll position before the page-refresh.

I am not sure what is the best way to keep the information -> `Cookies`, `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` for my case, because the user will usually open more sub-pages with "read more" buttons.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq10zyku/) (page refresh is not working on a fiddle).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aq10zyku/ (fiddle link doestn work in the question even with "code". )

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more about your page and what's initiating the refresh?  Is it a aspx page, php, vanilla html?

Comment: Thank you very much for getting into. Please see the fiddle. Its a html page on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise using `sessionStorage` for this.

First, remove all `onclick=refreshPage()` from your HTML. You want to keep all JS code inside your JS, and to set all handlers at one place. As a best practice, do not use `onclick` at all.

Next, create two functions: `loadState()` and `saveState()`. You will need to call call `loadState()` on every page load (refresh), and `saveState()` everytime a toggle button is clicked.

In your handler for clicks on button, also perform the page refresh.

The entire JS code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  loadState();
});

$('.read-more-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.read-more-content').toggleClass('hide');

  saveState();
  refreshPage();
});

// Fold or unfold each content based on state before refresh
// And go to same scroll position before refresh
function loadState() {
  let hidden_states = sessionStorage.getItem('hidden-states');
  if (!hidden_states) {
    return;
  }
  hidden_states = hidden_states.split(',');
  $('.read-more-content').each(function(i, elem) {
    if (hidden_states[i] === 'hide') {
      elem.classList.add('hide');
    }
    else {
      elem.classList.remove('hide');
    }
  });

  document.scrollingElement.scrollLeft = sessionStorage.getItem('scroll-x');
  document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = sessionStorage.getItem('scroll-y');
}

// Remember fold & unfold states, and scroll positions
function saveState() {
  let hidden_states = [];
  $('.read-more-content').each(function(i, elem) {
    hidden_states.push(elem.classList.contains('hide') ? 'hide' : 'show');
  });

  sessionStorage.setItem('hidden-states', hidden_states);
  sessionStorage.setItem('scroll-x', document.scrollingElement.scrollLeft);
  sessionStorage.setItem('scroll-y', document.scrollingElement.scrollTop);
}

function refreshPage() {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

---

**Note:** If at all possible, try to avoid a page refresh. Storing view states then recreating them after a refresh feels sub-optimal. In some browsers, it may also result in occasional scroll jump glitches as it repaints the restored states.

Lastly, consider if you really need jQuery for your project. Most functionality can be implemented in vanilla JS.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it. You did a awesome work in this short time. There is only 1 issue. When you open the page first, all content is collapsed instead of closed. could you fixed this? thank you :)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "collapsed instead of closed". Sounds like the same to me. In your code, you have a class `hide`. Are the terms closed, hide, collapsed the same? I suspect you mean you want all sections to be a certain state (either shown or hidden) by default, but you really need to be consistent and precise in terminology. Anyway, I believe the fix is really simple. I could probably fix it in a minute. But so can you! I don't want to steal the learning away from you, so I hope my code has given you enough to go on for now.

Comment: Yes, I found it self after a while. Thank you very much.